# Flutter Web Page to download a file from a server

Tags: flutter, dart

My goal for a school project is to make a website with Flutter. The Site should show multiple files as a list with a download button for each of the files. All simple so far.

My problem is that I am not able to download a file that is either stored locally or over a download URL. I have tried using the dart HTML plugin as well as the dio package to get this to work. No luck.

So my question is: Is there a way to make an "onPressed" event to download a local file or via a download URL?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can download a file from flutter with [this plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_downloader)

It is very simple to use. I am adding a snippet of code to integrate to your webview (naviagtionDelegate when it navigates to a download URL)

```
final taskId = await FlutterDownloader.enqueue(
  url: 'your download link',
  savedDir: 'the path of directory where you want to save downloaded files',
  showNotification: true, // show download progress in status bar (for Android)
  openFileFromNotification: true, // click on notification to open downloaded file (for Android)
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Although I am struggling to get this to work.
Currently this is how my code looks:

`void downloadFile() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await FlutterDownloader.initialize(debug: true);

  final taskId = await FlutterDownloader.enqueue(url:"https://groups.csail.mit.edu/graphics/classes/6.837/F03/models/teapot.obj",savedDir: "path to my downloads folder");
}`

This throws an UnimplementedError

Comment: Can you please paste the code at pastebin so that I can go through the problems

Comment: https://pastebin.com/zSff17Mv

That's the download method.

Comment: @BonuGT that's probably because this plugin is only developed for iOS and android and not for web..

Answer (score 0):

For everyone looking how to generate a PDF for the web with dart/flutter and looking to this :

```
Future<void> downloadPdfWeb() async {

  final pdf = pw.Document();

pdf.addPage(
    pw.Page(
      pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,
      build: (pw.Context context) {
        return pw.Center(
          child: pw.Text("An old falcon"),
        );
      },
    ),
  );

  final Uint8List bytes = await pdf.save();

  final blob = html.Blob([bytes]);
  final url = html.Url.createObjectUrlFromBlob(blob);
  final anchor = html.AnchorElement(href: url)
    ..setAttribute('download', 'z.pdf')
    ..click();
  html.Url.revokeObjectUrl(url);
}
```

I was stuck for a few days on it... ;)

Answer (score -1):

you can use the package [Url Launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher)

Once you installed you can do:
onPressed: () => launch('https://www.google.com/file.pdf')

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I maybe should have specified that I am not making a mobile app. So when using your code all it does is open a new tab in my browser with the file URL.